# How to multiply elements of php array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multiplication

I'm trying to translate a javascript function into php but having some problems with my arrays.  I need to iterate over the array elements, multiplying them all by a certain amount, but it's not changing the values.  Pretty sure it's because my syntax $coordinates_p[i][0] *= $scale; isn't correct, but I'm not sure what it should be!

Test code:

```
<?php

print "Starting.<br/>";

$scale = 100;

$coordinates_p = array();

$i = 0;
$x_coordinate = 1;
$y_coordinate = 2;
while ($i <= 1) {
    $coordinates_p[$i] = array(0 => $x_coordinate, 1 => $y_coordinate);
    $x_coordinate += 1;
    $y_coordinate += 2;
    $i++;
}

print "Unscaled: ";
print_r ($coordinates_p);
print "<br/>";

$i = 0;
while (isset($coordinates_p[i])) {
    $coordinates_p[i][0] *= $scale;
    $coordinates_p[i][1] *= $scale;
    $i++;
}

print "Scaled: ";
print_r ($coordinates_p);
print "<br/>";

print "Finished.";

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code just needs to change from

```
$coordinates_p[i][0] *= $scale;
$coordinates_p[i][1] *= $scale;
```

to

```
$coordinates_p[$i][0] *= $scale;
$coordinates_p[$i][1] *= $scale;
```

Comment: Keep on missing those!  But unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Mike then you also missed the one in the isset above those two. Always enable `error_reporting(-1)` on development servers and make sure you set your `display_errors` directive in php.ini and PHP will tell you about these things.

Comment: My bad, there was another one I'd missed.  Working fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in

```
while (isset($coordinates_p[i])) {
    $coordinates_p[i][0] *= $scale;
    $coordinates_p[i][1] *= $scale;
    $i++;
}
```

it should use $i not i.

like so:

```
while (isset($coordinates_p[$i])) {
    $coordinates_p[$i][0] *= $scale;
    $coordinates_p[$i][1] *= $scale;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. That will teach me to cut and paste from javascript!

Comment: jon_darkstar's answer here is also a good note - I was just fixing your code. Using the foreach approach would be "better" php. Even a for loop (bounded) would be a better approach than a potentially infinite while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how "deeply" you want to translate

> Shallow - put a $ in front of every variable
>
> Deeper - put $ in front of variables, change those while loops to foreach, change print to echo

```
//before
$i = 0;
while (isset($coordinates_p[i])) {
    $coordinates_p[i][0] *= $scale;
    $coordinates_p[i][1] *= $scale;
    $i++;
}

//Better PHP form
foreach($coordinates_p as $current)
{
   $current[0] *= $scale;
   $current[1] *= $scale;
}
```

They'll each run, but you're not really USING php if you do those while loops.  For a more extreme example, post code with lots of while loops up with a "python" tag and ask if it can be simplified.

foreach loops and echo are idiomatic php, while loops and print only works.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Never really learnt any programming language properly, just dabble around and try and get the end result I need.  Would probably be worth investing some time in it though, I seem to be doing more and more recently.  Thanks for the tip!